# rails passbook gem - issues with .p12 certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, passbook

I use this gem to export content in my rails app into an apple pass: https://github.com/frozon/passbook

I have followed all the instructions there but somehow I have issues with the exported .p12 certificate.

When exporting a pass in my app, I always get:

```
OpenSSL::PKCS12::PKCS12Error in PassbookPassesController#show
PKCS12_parse: mac verify failure
```

I have used the .p12 certificate of a third party agency before that has developed the rails app. With their certificate it all works fine but mine does not.
I obviously have modified the `teamIdentifier` and `passTypeIdentifier` in the pass.json file accordingly. So I also cannot really explain why the .p12 file is working although I have already modified the meta information.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using he correct passphrase for your p12 file?

Comment: indeed - that was too obvious. thank you